# Python/Numba: Unknown attribute error with scipy.special.gammainc()

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, anaconda, numba

I am having an error when running code using the @jit decorator. It appears that some information for the function `scipy.special.gammainc()` can't be located:

```
Failed at nopython (nopython frontend)
Unknown attribute 'gammainc' for Module(<module 'scipy.special' from 'C:\home\Miniconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\special\__init__.pyc'>) $164.2 $164.3 = getattr(attr=gammainc, value=$164.2)
```

Without the @jit decorator the code will run fine. Maybe there is something required to make the attributes of the scipy.special module visible to Numba?

Comment: Have you tried `from scipy import special` or `from scipy.special import ge...`?  Sometimes importing from `scipy` is tricky.

Comment: Thanks for these suggestions, unfortunately I am still getting the errors when I attempt all of the above import methods: Failed at nopython (nopython frontend)
Untyped global name 'gammainc'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that `gammainc` isn't one of the small list of functions that Numba inherently knows how to deal with (see http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/numpysupported.html) - in fact none of the scipy functions are. This means you can't use it in "nopython" mode, unfortunately - it just has to treat it as a normal python function call.

If you remove `nopython=True`, it should work. However, that isn't hugely satisfactory, because it may well be slower. Without seeing your code it's difficult to know exact what to suggest. However, in general:

- loops (that don't contain things like `gammainc`) will be sped up, even without nopython.
- `gammainc` is a "ufunc", which means it can be readily applied to a whole array at a time, and should run quickly anyway.
- you can call `func.inspect_types()` to see it's been able to compile.

As a trivial example:

```
from scipy.special import gammainc
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

@nb.jit # note - no "nopython"
def f(x):
  for n in range(x.shape[0]):
    x[n] += 1
  y = gammainc(x,2.5)
  for n in range(y.shape[0]):
    y[n] -= 1
  return y

f(np.linspace(0,20)) # forces it to be JIT'd and outputs an array
```

Then `f.inspect_types()` identifies the two loops as "lifted loops", meaning they'll be JIT'd and run quickly. The bit with `gammainc` is not JIT'd, but is applied to the whole array at once and so should be fast too.

Comment: Excellent response, David. Like you say the code runs fine without nopython=True. I was just trying to take things to the end and eek out the most from Numba as possible, but from your explanation above it sounds like I will nevertheless get performance improvements when compiling in object mode. I get what looks to be a 20% increase in performance when using \@jit with object mode on this one function containing gammainc, but I've been spoiled already with the massive gains I've seen after using \@jit on the other functions, so getting nopython mode to work on this function was my goal.