# Fast spearman correlation between two pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, parallel-processing, scipy

I want to apply spearman correlation to two pandas dataframes with the same number of columns (correlation of each pair of rows).

My objective is to compute the distribution of spearman correlations between each pair of rows (r, s) where r is a row from the first dataframe and s is a row from the second dataframe.

I am aware that similar questions have been answered before (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51470205/41977)). However, this question differs because I want to compare each row of first dataframe with ALL the rows in the second. Additionally, this is computationally intensive and it takes hours due to the size of my data. I want to parallelize it and possibly to rewrite it in order to speed it up.

I tried with numba but unfortunately it fails (similar issue to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31975205/python-numba-unknown-attribute-error-with-scipy-special-gammainc)) because it seems to not recognize [scipy spearmanr](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.spearmanr.html). My code is the following:

```
def corr(a, b):
    dist = []
    for i in range(a.shape[0]):
        for j in range(b.shape[0]):
            dist += [spearmanr(a.iloc[i, :], b.iloc[j, :])[0]]
    return dist
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## NEW ANSWER

```
from numba import njit
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

@njit
def mean1(a):
  n = len(a)
  b = np.empty(n)
  for i in range(n):
    b[i] = a[i].mean()
  return b

@njit
def std1(a):
  n = len(a)
  b = np.empty(n)
  for i in range(n):
    b[i] = a[i].std()
  return b
```

---

```
@njit
def c(a, b):
    ''' Correlation '''
    n, k = a.shape
    m, k = b.shape

    mu_a = mean1(a)
    mu_b = mean1(b)
    sig_a = std1(a)
    sig_b = std1(b)

    out = np.empty((n, m))

    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(m):
            out[i, j] = (a[i] - mu_a[i]) @ (b[j] - mu_b[j]) / k / sig_a[i] / sig_b[j]

    return out
```

---

```
r = df_test.rank(1).values
df_test.T.corr('spearman') == c(r, r)
```

## OLD ANSWER

Doing a Spearman Rank correlation is simply doing a correlation of the ranks.

#### Rank

We can leverage `argsort` to get ranks.  Though the `argsort` of the `argsort` does get us the ranks, we can limit ourselves to one sort by slice assigning.

```
def rank(a):
  i, j = np.meshgrid(*map(np.arange, a.shape), indexing='ij')

  s = a.argsort(1)
  out = np.empty_like(s)
  out[i, s] = j

  return out
```

---

#### Correlation

In the case of correlating ranks, the means and standard deviations are all predetermined by the size of the second dimension of the array.

You can accomplish this same thing without numba, but I'm assuming you want it.

```
from numba import njit

@njit
def c(a, b):
  n, k = a.shape
  m, k = b.shape

  mu = (k - 1) / 2
  sig = ((k - 1) * (k + 1) / 12) ** .5

  out = np.empty((n, m))

  a = a - mu
  b = b - mu

  for i in range(n):
    for j in range(m):
      out[i, j] = a[i] @ b[j] / k / sig ** 2

  return out
```

For posterity, we could avoid the internal loop altogether but this might have memory issues.

```
@njit
def c1(a, b):
  n, k = a.shape
  m, k = b.shape

  mu = (k - 1) / 2
  sig = ((k - 1) * (k + 1) / 12) ** .5

  a = a - mu
  b = b - mu

  return a @ b.T / k / sig ** 2
```

---

#### Demonstration

```
np.random.seed([3, 1415])

a = np.random.randn(2, 10)
b = np.random.randn(2, 10)

rank_a = rank(a)
rank_b = rank(b)

c(rank_a, rank_b)

array([[0.32121212, 0.01818182],
       [0.13939394, 0.55151515]])
```

If you were working with `DataFrame`

```
da = pd.DataFrame(a)
db = pd.DataFrame(b)

pd.DataFrame(c(rank(da.values), rank(db.values)), da.index, db.index)


          0         1
0  0.321212  0.018182
1  0.139394  0.551515
```

---

#### Validation

We can do a quick validation using `pandas.DataFrame.corr`

```
pd.DataFrame(a.T).corr('spearman') == c(rank_a, rank_a)

      0     1
0  True  True
1  True  True
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't get the same results using the two functions. I did a basic correlation of the same matrix (3x3) and then subtracted the two results. The diagonal is correct, other coefficients are different than 0 - I think the problem is in the `c()` function since the `rank()` is working correctly. Thanks

Comment: Can you explain more?  Show the data you used, steps you took, and results?

Comment: Yes, sorry - the comment space was very short. Here's a pastebin: https://pastebin.com/M5mFz8FJ

Comment: I have also to add that I'm not biased towards numba, if it's faster ok. But I want the fastest methodology.

Comment: I get all zeros.  Can you edit that paste bin to include an [mcve].  Meaning, include the data.  That way, I can copy and paste directly from the paste bin and run it.

Comment: I can't access dropbox from where I'm at.  I'm talking about providing a small sample of data within your paste bin just so we can make sure we're using the same data as we debug.

Comment: This should work https://pastebin.com/6f1j5Ybn . Let me know if it's ok. Thanks. I noticed that it may be related to ties resolution in the ranks.. maybe your code give different tie values? Since the data is very sparse and I expect a lot of ties.

Comment: Ahh!  I see now.  That's a big problem.  I didn't anticipate a sparse type array.  Meaning, I didn't expect lot's of zeroes.  I have to rethink.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180229/discussion-between-gc5-and-pirsquared).

Comment: This works, but I question its performance.  See if that helps you out.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a rowbased, uncompiled version of `scipy.stats.spearmanr` that uses ~ 5% of the time on large datasets with an example showing it produces the same result:

```
import numpy as np

import pandas as pd


def spearman_row(x, y):

    x = np.asarray(x)
    y = np.asarray(y)

    rx = rankdata_average(x)
    ry = rankdata_average(y)

    # print(rx)
    # print(ry)

    return compute_corr(rx, ry)

def compute_corr(x, y):

    # Thanks to https://github.com/dengemann

    def ss(a, axis):
        return np.sum(a * a, axis=axis)

    x = np.asarray(x)
    y = np.asarray(y)

    mx = x.mean(axis=-1)
    my = y.mean(axis=-1)

    xm, ym = x - mx[..., None], y - my[..., None]

    r_num = np.add.reduce(xm * ym, axis=-1)
    r_den = np.sqrt(ss(xm, axis=-1) * ss(ym, axis=-1))

    with np.errstate(divide='ignore', invalid="ignore"):

        r = r_num / r_den

    return r


def rankdata_average(data):

    """Row-based rankdata using method=mean"""

    dc = np.asarray(data).copy()
    sorter = np.apply_along_axis(np.argsort, 1, data)

    inv = np.empty(data.shape, np.intp)

    ranks = np.tile(np.arange(data.shape[1]), (len(data), 1))

    np.put_along_axis(inv, sorter, ranks, axis=1)

    dc = np.take_along_axis(dc, sorter, 1)

    res = np.apply_along_axis(lambda r: r[1:] != r[:-1], 1, dc)

    obs = np.column_stack([np.ones(len(res), dtype=bool), res])

    dense = np.take_along_axis(np.apply_along_axis(np.cumsum, 1, obs), inv, 1)

    len_r = obs.shape[1]

    nonzero = np.count_nonzero(obs, axis=1)
    obs = pd.DataFrame(obs)
    nonzero = pd.Series(nonzero)
    dense = pd.DataFrame(dense)

    ranks = []
    for _nonzero, nzdf in obs.groupby(nonzero, sort=False):

        nz = np.apply_along_axis(lambda r: np.nonzero(r)[0], 1, nzdf)

        _count = np.column_stack([nz, np.ones(len(nz)) * len_r])
        _dense = dense.reindex(nzdf.index).values

        _result = 0.5 * (np.take_along_axis(_count, _dense, 1) + np.take_along_axis(_count, _dense - 1, 1) + 1)

        result = pd.DataFrame(_result, index=nzdf.index)
        ranks.append(result)

    final = pd.concat(ranks).sort_index()

    return final


if __name__ == "__main__":

    from scipy.stats import rankdata, spearmanr
    from time import time

    np.random.seed(0)

    size = int(1e5), 5
    d1 = np.random.randint(5, size=size)
    d2 = np.random.randint(5, size=size)

    start = time()
    actual = spearman_row(d1, d2)
    end = time()
    print("actual", actual)
    print("rowbased took", end - start)

    start = time()
    expected = []
    for i in range(len(d1)):
        expected.append(spearmanr(d1[i], d2[i]).correlation)
    end = time()
    print("scipy took", end - start)

    expected = np.array(expected)

    print("largest diff", pd.Series(expected - actual).abs().max())
```

It prints:

```
rowbased took 3.6308434009552
scipy took 53.552557945251465
largest diff 2.220446049250313e-16
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas has a `corr` function with the support of `spearman`. It works on columns, so we can just transpose the dataFrame.

We will append df1 to df2 and calculate the correlation by iterating over each row

```
len_df1 = df1.shape[0]
df2_index = df2.index.values.tolist()


df = df2.append(df1).reset_index(drop=True).T
values = {i: [df.iloc[:,df2_index+[i]].corr(method='spearman').values] for i in range(len_df1)}
```

Comment: I think there's a problem on the use of `df2.index` since it is made of strings, while in the last two statements I think it is the rank of the columns (due to `reset_index()`). Thanks for the suggestion however, I am trying to build from here.

Comment: I don't have an idea about how the dataFrame looks like but you `reset_index()` once before the `df2_index` assignment and that should work.