# Scipy special functions with numba

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, jit, numba

This code fails:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit
import scipy.special as sp

@jit(nopython=True)
def f(a):
    return sp.xlogy(a, a)
  

a = np.array([1,2,0,1], dtype=float)
f(a)
```

It gives the following error

```
TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Unknown attribute 'xlogy' of type Module(<module 'scipy.special' from '/home/yair/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/special/__init__.py'>)
```

However, I believe it should work, becuase it says [here](https://numba-special.readthedocs.io/en/latest/numba_special.html#) that `xlogy` could be overloaded. An [answer from 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31975205/python-numba-unknown-attribute-error-with-scipy-special-gammainc) says this could not be done (for some other function) but maybe I thought it changed.

Of course, I can implement it myself but it would be nice to use a known solution.

EDIT:
Per Andras Deak's suggestion below, I tried using `numba-scipy`. I cannot get it to work and was hoping for some usage example. Here are my attempts - they all fail, see errors below:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit
import numba_scipy
import scipy as sp
from scipy import special as spc

@jit(nopython=True)
def f1(a):
    return numba_scipy.special.xlogy(a,a)

@jit(nopython=True)
def f2(a):
    return numba_scipy.xlogy(a,a)


@jit(nopython=True)
def f3(a):
    return sp.special.xlogy(a,a)

@jit(nopython=True)
def f4(a):
    return spc.xlogy(a,a)


a = np.array([0,1,2])

try:
    f1(a)
except Exception as e:
    print('f1 fails')
    print(e)

try:
    f2(a)
except Exception as e:
    print('f2 fails')
    print(e)

try:
    f3(a)
except Exception as e:
    print('f3 fails')
    print(e)

try:
    f4(a)
except Exception as e:
    print('f4 fails')
    print(e)
```

Complete error message:

```
/home/yair/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numba/core/dispatcher.py:238: UserWarning: Numba extension module 'numba_scipy' failed to load due to 'ValueError(No function '__pyx_fuse_0pdtr' found in __pyx_capi__ of 'scipy.special.cython_special')'.
  entrypoints.init_all()
f1 fails
Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython rewrites)
module 'numba_scipy' has no attribute 'special'
f2 fails
Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython rewrites)
module 'numba_scipy' has no attribute 'xlogy'
f3 fails
Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Unknown attribute 'xlogy' of type Module(<module 'scipy.special' from '/home/yair/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/special/__init__.py'>)

File "example.py", line 19:
    def f3(a):
        return sp.special.xlogy(a,a)
        ^

During: typing of get attribute at example.py (19)

File "example.py", line 19:
    def f3(a):
        return sp.special.xlogy(a,a)
        ^

f4 fails
Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Unknown attribute 'xlogy' of type Module(<module 'scipy.special' from '/home/yair/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/special/__init__.py'>)

File "example.py", line 23:
    def f4(a):
        return spc.xlogy(a,a)
        ^

During: typing of get attribute at example.py (23)

File "example.py", line 23:
    def f4(a):
        return spc.xlogy(a,a)
        ^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're having install issues according to a comment, I would especially suggest using [numba-scipy](https://numba-scipy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/special.html) instead, from the creators of numba itself ([link to pypi](https://pypi.org/project/numba-scipy/)). It's always a good idea to use first-party extensions to packages.

---

The [very documentation you linked](https://numba-special.readthedocs.io/en/latest/numba_special.html)  relates to `numba_special`. If you look at the [main page](https://numba-special.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) you'll see the first example:

```
>>> import numba
>>> import scipy.special as sc
>>> import numba_special  # The import generates Numba overloads for special
>>> @numba.njit
... def gamma_plus_1(x):
...     return sc.gamma(x) + 1.0
...
>>> gamma_plus_1(5.0)
25.0
```

Note the `import numba_special` line you're missing.

You will also have to install [numba-special](https://pypi.org/project/numba-special/) first. Also note the warning on the project's page:

> Installing
>
> Numba special depends on SciPy and Numba. Until the fix for [this issue](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/4133) is included in a Numba release, numba_special must be installed against the master branch of Numba.

Comment: Great, but now I cannot install it...
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

Comment: @Yair as the error says you have to read the rest of what was printed. There should be a mostly helpful error message.

Comment: @Yair see my update: I suggest using numba's own extension package.

Comment: Thanks! Can you give a usage example? I cannot get it to work (see  updated question).

Comment: @YairDaon I'll tell you when I get a response on https://github.com/numba/numba-scipy/issues/44 :) Things don't look good, but fingers crossed.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling xlogy function from scipy.special, actually for the functions called by @jit decorated functions also need to be @jit decorated.
So that's why xlogy is not compatible with your f function and numba throwing error. The workaround could be:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit


@jit(nopython=True)
def myxlogy(x,y):
    return x*np.log(y)


@jit(nopython=True)
def f(a):
    return myxlogy(a,a)

a = np.array([1,2,0,1], dtype=float)
f(a)
>>array([0.        , 1.38629436,        nan, 0.        ])
```

Comment: Actually this is not a good solution. We want 0log(0) = 0 and this solution does not do that.